# Значение текстового поля не определяется даже с помощью document.getElementById.value

Tags: javascript, html

При определении с помощью document.getElementById.value значение определяется только у однострочного текстового поля, а у текстового поля-[object HTMLTextAreaElement]. Тем не менее, их значение определяется одинаковым методом.

JS:

```
var theme = document.getElementById('theme').value;
var quest = document.getElementById('q').value;
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="theme" class="form-control">
<textarea class="form-control" id="q"></textarea></br>
<input type="button" onclick="sendq();" class="btn btn-info btn-block" value="Отправить">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/7qadLaz0/

html

```
<input type="text" id="theme" class="form-control">
<textarea class="form-control" id="qi"></textarea>
<input type="button" onclick="sendq(); return false;" class="btn btn-info btn-block" value="Отправить">
```

javascript

```
function sendq() 
{
    var theme = document.getElementById('theme').value;
    var quest = document.getElementById('qi').value;
    alert(theme);
    alert(quest);
}
```

Работает без проблем в FF39 и IE11.

P.S. И свойство `value` есть у `textarea` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_textarea.asp

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 0):

У `<input>` есть атрибут `value`, когда как у `<textarea>` его нет. Зато у `<textarea>` есть замечательный атрибут `innerHTML`.

Comment: У textarea есть свойство value :P

Comment: И тем не менее, даже через innerHTML ничего не выходит.